# Background image load fast onload without white background

Tags: html, css

I have to change background image on page load as I use onload on body or i have to use window.onload which one would be faster to be background image load without showing white background as page load. and where I have to put it on head or body after tag so it can shows as site opens without showing white background

```
 $('body').onload('background-image', 'url(http://picture.de/image.png)');
```

Comment: actually i have to load image first without showing white background If i remove the script from my code then it's load faster without showing white background

Comment: image always have a loading time. So when it is loading, there's just a background color there. you can speed up by compressing, base64 image etc.

Comment: there is no script for which i load first in html and take image faster and after that all style and script run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that once an image has been loaded in the browser, it will be in the browser cache and will load much faster the next time it is used as long as the image hasn't expire from the browser cache.

For your problem, there are two things you try.

1) Try to preload images with javascript:

```
function preloadImage(url) {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
}
```

2) Optimise your images. Use a tool like [tinypng](https://tinypng.com/) in order to compress your images. Most of the times you will save up to 60%. If you have a container that you want the image to fit in, try to resize the images into the width and height of that container (use width and height).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below example.
http://jsbin.com/pozadujeca/edit?js,console,output
and using CSS you can apply the background color to the image load or show loader at background.

I hope it will help you
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't take the js route, instead I would just save the image as a progressive jpg: https://optimus.io/support/progressive-jpeg/

Answer (score 0):

first you can understand the flow of js engine .how it works .you can put in head if you want to load it when js is loaded .if you want to display background image then you must put into html .because html loaded before js in browser